# Abundance of penitente ice formations in the solar system

Tags: planet, exoplanet, mars, pluto, weather

When researching for my [question on extraterresitral snow](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40917/extraterrestrial-snow), I learned about a rare [snow formation called penitente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penitente_(snow_formation)) which seems to be found on various (dwarf) planets, like Earth, Mars, and Pluto. Interestingly, these spike-like structures are an important place for life in extreme environments (on Earth) as shown by a [study 2019 of penitentes in the Adnes](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/15230430.2019.1618115), but this is not what I after.

My question: **How abundant are penitentes in our solar system?** Are they any estimates in terms of area covered or total ice volume present as penitentes per planet? I would also be interested in actual pictures of extraterrestrial nieves penitentes (including the image source).

#### How it looks like

[image: ESO/B. Tafreshi (twanight.org)]

Penitentes of the Atacama Desert, cropped from http://www.eso.org/public/images/potw1522a/

#### References

The [Reference list of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penitente_(snow_formation)#References) already offers a nice reading list, but I feel the list is far from exhaustive. What I found worth bookmarking:

- A [blog by Yurong Yu from February 2017](https://glacierhub.org/2017/02/14/penitentes-found-on-pluto/) served me as a starting point.
- There is an 2019 article by T. Giang Nguyen, Christina L.Smith, Alexandra Innanen and John E. Moores called
  [Simulating the formation of Martian penitentes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0032063318304483)
- The same John E. Moores published meeting notes called [Penitentes at Tartarus Dorsa, Pluto.](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2017/pdf/1664.pdf)

Comment: Another article on the penitentes of Pluto: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.icarus.2016.08.025